# getText from custom dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, gettext

I've been trying to make it so that I can save whatever data the user inputs into the custom dialog's `EditText` with no success. The app just crashes everytime on the line that has the `getText()` function. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
public void comments(View v){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder2;

    builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    builder2.setTitle("Recipe Comments");
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comments, null);

    builder2.setView(view)
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...
                    EditText text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.comments);
                    String temp = text.getText().toString();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    builder2.create();
    builder2.show();
}
```

Here is the StackTraces:

> 08-22 23:43:38.111 10837-10897/com.example.wesle.wsuuioption1
>   I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>       08-22 23:43:43.568 10837-10837/com.example.wesle.wsuuioption1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       08-22 23:43:43.571 10837-10837/com.example.wesle.wsuuioption1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.wesle.wsuuioption1, PID: 10837
>                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.wesle.wsuuioption1.MainActivity$7.onClick(MainActivity.java:2936)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: POST your logcat so people can find what mistake you did it ....

Comment: Just posted it, thanks.

Comment: please check in your `R.layout.fragment_comments` id of edittext is `comments` or post your xml file

Comment: is your `R.id.comments` belongs to  `R.layout.fragment_comments` ?

Comment: That fixed it Kapil. Thanks!!

Comment: it''s fine code... check your id comments is there in your fragment_comments.xml......

Answer (score 0):

Make connection her before setting view and make it final too.

```
public void comments(View v){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder2;

    builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    builder2.setTitle("Recipe Comments");
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comments, null);

    // Make connection her before setting view.
    final EditText text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.comments);

    builder2.setView(view)
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...
                    //EditText text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.comments);
                    String temp = text.getText().toString();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    builder2.create();
    builder2.show();
}
```

Comment: Still crashed on me with that change

Answer (score 0):

You can not get components by `views`. Just get it from `DialogInterface` `object`

```
    public void comments(View v){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder2;

    builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    builder2.setTitle("Recipe Comments");
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comments, null);


    builder2.setView(view)
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...
                    EditText text = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.comments);
                    String temp = text.getText().toString();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    builder2.create();
    builder2.show();
}
```